# Postback via webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

I work for a radio station and they want a now playing and coming next on their radio player.

I currently have xml that I will be saving to my live webserver via a webservice. Is there a way to only get the radio player to postback when the xml changes rather than every second via a timer control? We have had performance issues with frequent postbacks in the past so would like to avoid crashing our server. I am using c# asp.net 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally i would recommend doing this with ajax. You can then cache the response at the server side so you dont need to do any heavy lifting in the bulk of requests.

What you want to do is to have your ajax query the server every 10s or so to get the current and next song as a json response. Take the response and put it into your page.

In asp.net you could also possibly do this with an update panel but this would cause significantly more load on both the server and the client.

Answer (score 0):

Comet solution or ETag may help